# Matching Column B with A, and then sorting B with its expanded selection

Tags: excel, sorting, vlookup

I have to sets of data.

The first set is just a bunch of IDs.

The second set is the same set of IDs and other data related to each ID.

But the second set of IDs is not in the same order as the first set.

So how do I get the second set to match up in the same order as the first set and also sort the items related to it?

So, here is an unsorted example:

[image]

I need to get from that to the following:

[image]

Anyone know the simplest way to do this, keeping in mind that the 2nd set has to be sorted along with its relations?

JH

Comment: You can just highlight only the second array and sort that.

Comment: I dont want to sort alphabetically. I want to sort exactly as it shows in column A. In my example its alphabetical but in reality, column A is not Alphabetical.

Comment: Create a mapping on the first one such that all alphas are = 1, all betas = 2 and so on. Append that mapping to the second table with a lookup, then sort on the appended ID.

Comment: Sadly, I am not too familiar with excel or formulas.

Any explanation?

Comment: Sure - it's getting beyond the scope of a comment. I'll post an answer, give me about 5 minutes

Comment: All right, take a look and let me know if that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't know if you have any duplicate IDs in the first or second, but we'll cover them anyways.

First, create an enumeration to hold the sort order of what you have in the first table.

```
 =IF(ROW(A2)=2,1,IF(B2=B1,A1,A1+1))
```

[image]

This basically just keeps the order that you have. If it's the first row you're using, give it a 1. If the ID on the current row is the same as the previous (a3 = alpha, a2 = alpha), keep whatever the previous ID was (so that duplicates are enumerated identically). Otherwise, increment the ID.

Then, on your other table, bring over the ID you created with a lookup formula - index match, vlookup both work.

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$5, MATCH(E2, $B$2:$B$5, 0))
```

[image]

Finally, just sort the new lookup column on the second table.

**Alternatively**, you can cut out the first step of enumerating them and just use MATCH on your table 2 IDs to table 1 IDs and it will return the row position that it is in.

```
=MATCH(id in second table, <array of IDs in first table>, 0)
```

You can then sort based on that. It may or may not be more intuitive to do it one way or the other.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this but I will try and give it a go and see if it works.

Thanks a lot.